# How to apply different amount of impulse(force) to the PhysicsBody object (cocos2d-x)?

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-physics, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk, physics-engine

Given the sprite with physics body `ball`, I want to apply different amount of the force to it in different directions. (And thus different distance for it to fly).

In the builtin physics engine (based on chipmunk) I am only able to do something like `ball->getPhysicsBody()->applyImpulse(Vec2(X, Y));`. But how to change the force of that impulse, I want to be able to apply different Impulse to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question,
in cocos2d-v3 `applyImpulse(..)` as well as `applyForce(..)` takes vector that specifies direction and the *norm/length* of that vector can be seen as the "amount" of force applied. Simply, `applyForce(Vec2(1,1))` and `applyForce(Vec2(100,100))` would both apply force directed at top right corner but in latter case the "amount" of that force is more.